# php mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php

Which one is "good syntax":

```
    $_GET['user'] = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
    $_GET['hash'] = mysql_real_escape_string($hash);
```

or

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['user']);
$hash = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['hash']);
```

Sorry for stupid question :/

Comment: Hah, I'll take my change with the second :)

Comment: Like others said, second approach is better. Though, you should also check if `$_GET['user']` and `$_GET['hash']` exist with `isset()` (or `empty`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### NONE.

If the first example you're doing `mysql_real_escape_string()` on an undefined variable.
In the second example you forgot the triling `)` for the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function.

**Correct:**

```
  <?php
    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['user']);
    $hash = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['hash']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really want to override your $_GET superglobal, then the first could be correct. But I'd guess you don't and you want the second one, although you might want to fix the missing bracket.